# oracle sqlplus won't run script

Tags: sqlplus

```
SQL> desc product
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 P_CODE                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 P_DESCRIPT                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35)
 P_INDATE                                  NOT NULL DATE
 P_QOH                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 P_MIN                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 P_PRICE                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
 P_DISCOUNT                                NOT NULL NUMBER(5,2)
 V_CODE                                             NUMBER(38)

SQL> @ld_product.sql;
--sqlplus does nothing for this script--insert product

set linesize 500;
set sqlbl on;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('11QER/31','Power painter, 15 pal, 3-nozzle','03-Nov-13','8','5','109.99','0.00','25595');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('13-Q2/P2','7.25-in.pwr.saw blade','13-Dec-13','32','15','14.99','0.05','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('14-Q1/L3','9.00-in.pwr.saw blade','13-Nov-13','18','12','17.49','0.00','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('1548-QQ2','Hrd.cloth,1/4-in.,2x50','15-Jan-14','15','8','39.95','0.00','23119');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('1558-QW1','Hrd.cloth,1/2-in.,3x50','15-Jan-14','23','5','43.99','0.00','23119');
/*
set define off;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('2232/QTY','B&D jigsaw,12-in.blade','30-Dec-13','8','5','109.92','0.05','24288');

set define off;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('2232/QWE','B&D jigsaw,8-in.blade','24-Dec-13','8','5','99.87','0.05','24288');

set define off;
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('2238/QPD','B&D cordless drill, 1/2-in.','20-Jan-14','12','5','38.95','0.05','25595');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('23109-HB','Claw hammer','20-Jan-14','23','10','9.95','0.10','21225');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('23114-AA','Sledge hammer, 12 lb.','02-Jan-14',' 8','5','14.40','0.05','  ');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('547?8-2T','Rat-tail file,1/8-in.fine','15-Dec-13','43','20','4.99','0.00','21344');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('89-WRE-Q','Hicut chain saw, 16 in.','07-Feb-14','11','5','256.99','0.05','24288');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('PVC23DRT','PVC pipe, 3.5-in., 8-ft','20-Feb-14','188','75','5.87','0.00','  ');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('SM-18277','1.25-in.metal screw,25','01-Mar-14','172','75','6.99','0.00','21225');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('SW-23116','2.5-in.wd.screw,50','24-Feb-14','237','100','8.45','0.00','21231');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('WR3/TT3','Steel matting, 4'x8'x1/6",.5" mesh','17-Jan-14','18','5','119.95','0.10','25595');
*/
```

Comment: What do you meam by "does nothing"? You get no output at all (is feedback on?), or you get errors, or it seems to run but you can't see the data in another session, or if you query in the same session? Are you being prompted for a variable value? What is your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT - you're supplying a string that has to be implicitly converted. Why are you enclosing numbers in quotes, and what is your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue a COMMIT at the end in order to save your inserts to the database.
You could also:

SET AUTOCOMMIT ON:

which tells sqlplus to issue a commit automatically after each statement if you wish.  Could be risky though, as you can't rollback a goof then. Read up on it first.